# Confidence interval for Standardized Mortality Ratio

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, ratio, mortality

So in a number of places, for example [here](https://ibis.health.state.nm.us/resource/SMR_ISR.html), I've seen stated without explanation that the standard error of the SMR (at 95% confidence threshold) is simply

$$
SE_{SMR} = 1.96 * \frac{\sqrt O}{E}
$$

Where $O$ is the observed count of fatalities and $E$ is the expected count (the origin of this expectation is irrelevant).  I haven't been able to find a derivation of this anywhere nor can I see how, for example, it derives from any of the means for calculating a [binomial proportion confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).  Can someone explain this?

**Edit**: This question was asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/345275/confidence-interval-of-standardized-mortality-ratio) a couple of years ago, but again states this formula without really explaining why it is correct.  The relation to the Poisson distribution helps (h/t @whuber) but doesn't make it completely clear, for me anyway.

Comment: I believe I covered this at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/493749/919.

Comment: @whuber Thanks.  That it comes from assuming a Poisson distribution definitely helps, but for standard error shouldn't we we in addition be dividing by $\sqrt{N}$?  And how does the inv. pdf of the normal distribution enter in exactly?

Comment: This is all standard -- which means you can find many posts about these topics both here, on the Web, and in elementary textbooks.  The Normal distribution is an approximation for large counts.