# Calculate standard error from confidence interval obtained for standardised incidence ratio

Tags: r, meta-analysis, epidemiology

I would like to do a meta-analysis  and pool data for standardised incidence ratio (SIR). I have the estimates for SIR and the corresponding 95% confidence interval (CI) for all studies. The CI are calculated using different methods, some fisher's exact test and some using normal approximation.

I understand from this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/345275/confidence-interval-of-standardized-mortality-ratio) the formula for different methods to calculate CI, but how about the standard error? How can we calculate SE from CI, number of observed cases etc. I can't seem to find the formula.